# The issues of common ground with voltmeter and ammeters

Tags: power-supply, shunt, voltmeter

Apologies if this post is, yet again, another noob in electronics. I have an engineering degree in audio but have newly found a passion for electronics and am teaching myself as I go.

I am trying to build a benchtop power supply from an old ATX power supply I have laying around.

I have tested the ATX supply, as well as done research and know that there is a **common ground** amongst all outputs of the supply.

I recently bought 3 x 100V 50A [voltmeter ammeters.](https://www.communica.co.za/products/dpm-cmu-digital-dual-100v-50a-rb)

**Specifications:**

```
Wiring voltage: 4.5-30V DC
Note: The maximum input voltage can not exceed 30V, otherwise there is the danger of burning
Working current: ≤20mA
Measuring range: DC 0-100V 0-50A
Minimum resolution (V): 0.1V
Refresh rate: ≥100mS / times
Measure accuracy: 1% (± 1 digit)
Minimum resolution (A): 0.01A
Operating temperature: -15 to 70° c
```

[image: Image of voltmeter ammeter]

[image: Wiring diagram of meter using an external shunt]

I would like to have 3 sets of bindings posts, *this will be my "load"*, 12V, 5V and 3.3V. Each circuit will have its own voltmeter ammeter. I know the issue, *but also the reason they're so inexpensive*, is that the shunt is connected to the negative side of the load, and I know this can be a major issue because all the outputs have a common ground. I'm just not sure **WHY** it's an issue.

I considered placing respectable relays (controlled with a toggle switch) within the negative of each shunt to be able to disconnect the meters which I am not using. But this would then in turn mean I am not able to use more than one output at a time.

**I have thought about these 2 options but I am not sure if they will solve the issue because the meters are still linked to the common ground:**

1. I can connect the 5V and 12V voltmeter ammeter's power input to their DC supply voltage (running to the load) from the ATX supply, since the power input of the meter needs to be between 4.5 - 30V, and the 3.3V I can connected to a seperate 5V supply line which I take from the ATX too.
2. I can connect all meters to a seperate supply voltage I take from the ATX. I.e. each meter has a supply voltage for its power in (1 x 12V line and 2 x 5V line) and each has s supply voltage running to its load.

Please forgive me, I have not drawn up any schematics because I'm not sure if this will even work.

**MY QUESTIONS ARE**

1. Why is common ground an issue when it comes to the meters? Is it to do with shorting of the shunts? I don't have a thorough understanding of the issue and thus cannot solve the problem.
2. If I galvanically isolated the supply voltage of the power input of each meter would this help solve the issue?
3. If I have 3 circuits but only one circuit had a meter, would that meter be affected if the other 2 circuits operated at the same time (with a load on them?)

Please help. I'm sorry if my post is not clear. If I must draw up some schematics I can, although they'd be rudimentary.

Comment: Ah, I have been using this type of cheap voltage/current meters for a couple of years. They are very good, except one thing. Every time I need to connect a new one, I need to study very carefully the user guide and scratch my little head hard in order to make sure I would not go wrong. I always use one such current/voltage for only one power source. I am not sure your situation. It would be nice if you can draw the schematic for your three meter set. I know the cause of possible trouble: the current meter might be "floating" and not allowing you to ground the way you wish.

Comment: something like INA3221 could be used to measure all three voltages and currents, but you need a computer like arduino or raspberry pi to read it and display the results,

Comment: Drawing up a simple schematic is where you find out the detail of what happens with the meter shunts and the common ground terminals. Just do it for two meters with two loads.

Comment: It appears that the current shunt sensor must be wired into the ground return. In the common-ground ATX, you *really want* all ground paths to have zero ohms, otherwise crap on one-of-three supplies influences the other two. I'll bet that this was such a problem in ATX computers that it was abandoned in favour of a single-supply. If you intend on using more than one-of-three outputs at the same time, consider not using current shunts, and only use the voltage measuring function: **One ground, uninterrupted**

Comment: @Audiosine, your wiring diagram showing a DC load, but the picture is a motor, which is an inductive load. This might be a problem, because when you switch off the motor, there might be a huge back EMF current flow back to the meter and PSU, if you don't have a flyback diode, ... Ah bed time, see you tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback. The load will vary depending on what projects i use the benchtop for. I haven't played around much with benchtop supplies instead just using those ac-dc laptop jacks to power projects. So I'm not really even sure I'll use more than one output on it?

Comment: The problem is that the volt meters sense wire need to be connected to the negative of the shunt/power for the load. As seen in the diagram. Would it be possible to disconnect the positive of the shunt - there by breaking the current measuring capabilities but completing the voltage meters circuit - therefore being able to measure 2 of the voltages of the circuits (with no load on those circuits) and allowing me to meter current and voltage of the third? If this makes sense?   Thanks again everyone!

Comment: @tong01 Thanks! i get you. So it would make sense for me to connect a fly back diode. On the outputs of each voltage? 3.3V, 5V and 12V respectively?

Comment: I will make sure to play around with the meters connected, draw up a schematic and the respond. Thanks @Neil_UK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the ATX supply there is only one ground (all the black wires coming out are connected to the same circuit node)

so when some current flows out on the 12V output it could flow back in on any oV outputs, if you have three of these little meters connected to your test circuit they'll probably all get some of the return current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6jEgd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

assuming a load with the 5V and 12V parts sharing the same ground

current flows in the red section meaning thast the 5V and 12V ammeters get a combined reading that equals the total current, but not a precise reading of each supply current.

> Why is common ground an issue when it comes to the meters? Is it to do with shorting of the shunts? I don't have a thorough understanding of the issue and thus cannot solve the problem.

it makes it impossible to separate the return currents if the load also has a common ground,

> If I galvanically isolated the supply voltage of the power input of each meter would this help solve the issue?

Yes that would solve this issue. DC-DC isolators capable of several amps are quite expensive though

> If I have 3 circuits but only one circuit had a meter, would that meter be affected if the other 2 circuits operated at the same time (with a load on them?)

yes it would, the meter measures the return current so return current from the other supply branches could stall pass throug it, or return through an un-metered path.

Comment: Thanks Jansen for your answer! You have helped me a ton and i genuinely appreciate your response and time! Just to clarify only if i galvanically isolated the power for the load it would it solve the problem? And not if only the power for the meter was galvanically isolated? Because I'm assuming the grounds are all linked so even if i isolated the power for the load I would have to do the same for the power for the meter? As you say it is quite pricey to get some sort of isolation for a substantial current.

Comment: I guess it would possibly make sense for me to rather have a single meter which switches between 3.3V, 5V and 12V lines? Possibly using a combination of relays for the current shunt and rortary switch for voltage? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: whatever you do it will read the sum of all the currents

Comment: @Jansen. Thanks! I reckon the best way forward will be to install them but only use one circuit at a time. Appreciate it. And if i use multiple circuits make use of my multimeter.

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

How to wire up 3 sets of cheap volt ampere meters for the corresponding 3 power units 3.3, 5V, and 12V, of the ATX 12 PSU, taking consideration that the 3 ATX powers have a common ground.

---

***Answer***

Firstly, let us look at the [user guide's wiring diagram](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32951970091.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000060.2.57a8677fhl0rq8&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.13339.169870.0&scm_id=1007.13339.169870.0&scm-url=1007.13339.169870.0&pvid=b7f02854-bd33-4c91-92ea-a05d5ec0b944&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller,scm-url:1007.13339.169870.0,pvid:b7f02854-bd33-4c91-92ea-a05d5ec0b944,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%230_668%23808%234094%23195_668%23888%233325%2319_668%232846%238109%23278_668%232717%237560%23300_668%231000022185%231000066058%230_668%233468%2315613%23468).

---

[image: va meter 1]

---

[image: va meter 2]

---

[image: va meter 3]

---

Secondly, there is also a [wiring demo video in the product](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32824062417.html?spm=a2g0w.search0302.3.89.202533f5f0m6yS&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=5a13517c-07e2-4886-b59b-f963329626f7&algo_expid=5a13517c-07e2-4886-b59b-f963329626f7-12), but I found it not that worth watching.

---

Thirdly, let us make sure if we can connect all three together with correct grounding,  with no risk of something melting down or blowing up.

The voltage meter and ampere meter are in the black box, so we need to read the wiring diagrams and reverse engineer/image what is inside the black box.  The following [product sheet](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.334.191a1230kc7UTK&id=557756373689&ns=1&abbucket=13#detail) (Ref 5) includes the most detailed wiring diagrams.

---

[image: wiring diagram]

---

Now let me see, according to [Thevnin's Theorem](http://physics.wm.edu/%7Eevmik/classes/Physics_252_Analog_Electronics/weekly_pdf_slides/week2_slides.pdf), what goes in at black, -ve terminal of a PSU must come out at red. +ve terminal of the same PSU.  In other words, even the three PSUs have grounds connected, the amount of current coming out of the positive side of a PSUPSU must come back with the same quantity at the -ve side of the same PSU, ...  So I think it is 99.9% OK that the grounds of the 3 ATX's 3V3/5V0/12V can be (or already) connected together.

***Warning:*** *I am just a friendly hobbyist.  No guarantee no nothing won't melt down or blow up.*

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***References***

(1) [DPM/CMU DIGITAL DUAL 100V 50A Voltmeter Ammeter with shunt (OP's VA meter)](https://www.communica.co.za/products/dpm-cmu-digital-dual-100v-50a-rb)

(2) [VA Meter Productsheet - AliExpress](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32951970091.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000060.2.57a8677fhl0rq8&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.13339.169870.0&scm_id=1007.13339.169870.0&scm-url=1007.13339.169870.0&pvid=b7f02854-bd33-4c91-92ea-a05d5ec0b944&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller,scm-url:1007.13339.169870.0,pvid:b7f02854-bd33-4c91-92ea-a05d5ec0b944,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%230_668%23808%234094%23195_668%23888%233325%2319_668%232846%238109%23278_668%232717%237560%23300_668%231000022185%231000066058%230_668%233468%2315613%23468)

(3) [VA Meter Wiring Demo Video (not that worth watching](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32824062417.html?spm=a2g0w.search0302.3.89.202533f5f0m6yS&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=5a13517c-07e2-4886-b59b-f963329626f7&algo_expid=5a13517c-07e2-4886-b59b-f963329626f7-12)

(4) [TaoBao Volt/Ampere Meter Catalog (in Chinese)](https://s.taobao.com/search?spm=&_tb_token_=ebb4e9f084e09&q=%E7%94%B5%E5%8E%8B%E7%94%B5%E6%B5%81%E8%A1%A8%20%E6%95%B0%E6%98%BE%20%E5%8F%8C%E6%98%BE&suggest=0_1&_input_charset=utf-8&wq=%E9%9B%BB%E5%A3%93%E9%9B%BB%E6%B5%81%E8%A1%A8&suggest_query=%E9%9B%BB%E5%A3%93%E9%9B%BB%E6%B5%81%E8%A1%A8&source=suggest)

(5) [DC0-100V 1A 10A 50A 100A LED DC Double Display (Voltage/Current) with fine tuning option, and ***very detailed wiring diagrams***)](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.334.191a1230kc7UTK&id=557756373689&ns=1&abbucket=13#detail)

(6) [Kirchhoff’s laws, Thévenin’s and Norton’s theorems - Eugeniy E. Mikhailov, The College of William & Mary](http://physics.wm.edu/%7Eevmik/classes/Physics_252_Analog_Electronics/weekly_pdf_slides/week2_slides.pdf)

---